# mysql_fetch_row getting columns not rows

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use mysql_fetch_row to get the individual rows from a database, however when I echo it its putting the columns as rows for example $row_columns[0] is column 1 and $row_columns[1] is column 2, allow me to show you the code I am using.

```
mysql_select_db($database_Takeaway, $Takeaway);
    $query_columns = "SELECT * FROM `rest_site` WHERE linkid = '$rest_id'";
    $columns = mysql_query($query_columns, $Takeaway) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_columns = mysql_fetch_row($columns);
```

and to display it.

```
echo($row_columns[0])
```

I tried

> print_r($row_columns)

and thats feeding back the following

> Array ( [0] => 1001 [1] => [2] => [3] => 0 [4] => [5] => 1837 [6]
>   => Test Title [7] => Test Text [8] => [9] => [10] => )

The above is all 1 row of data whereas I need it to be the individual columns so I can do something like the following.

```
echo $row_columns[0]['name']
echo $row_columns[0]['postcode']
```

I have been doing a lot of searching on this and can't seem to find anything that helps, I have checked php.net as well as general google searching and of course Stack Overflow so would really appreciate your help on this.

I hope I have made the question clear.

Thanks

Comment: That's what it's supposed to do, it returns the next row from the query. There's no mysql function to return all rows at once, you have to call one of the mysql_fetch_XXX functions in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` to get results with column names.

Additionally if you don't put it into a loop you will always receive only the first row of query. Better use is:

```
mysql_select_db($database_Takeaway, $Takeaway);
$query_columns = "SELECT * FROM `rest_site` WHERE linkid = '$rest_id'";
$columns = mysql_query($query_columns, $Takeaway) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row_columns = mysql_fetch_assoc($columns)) {
    echo $row_columns["name"];  
    echo $row_columns["postcode"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_row` is an enumerated array only.

You are looking for `mysql_fetch_array` which results an associative and enumerated array so you can use a  string literal array index.

You should also look into mysqli or PDO, as mysql is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.

Link: [mysql_fetch_array Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Answer (score -1):

`SELECT *` is no proper statement, you'd better list all columns that you need. Making them explicit also helps us answering your questions.

Also, please always escape input to the query! `mysql_real_escape_string()`

As a guess, I think you are missing the fact that fetching a query result always must be fetched row by row. Do you know you'll need a loop?

Also, if you want to have the column names, use `mysql_fetch_assoc()`.

Comment: Yes, but I'd criticize that "*" is almost always bad for performance and, like this example proves, blurs the vision on which data is actually dealt with. `SELECT *` works ok in the first draft of a query, but if it isn't changed to explicit columns, any new column in this table will automatically be pulled by this query. Just imagine a user table starts being small and then gets added a column for the user avatar, allowing 1 MB per user, and this query will never deal with the image. Bye bye, performance.